# Ada V. Hagerty confinement

Tags: medicine

Ada V Hagerty is my great-grandmother. She was confined to the Eastern Indiana Hospital for the Insane in July, 1925. She was a resident there until her death on April 2, 1952.

I am seeking medical records, information as to her diagnosis and treatment.

Also, I believe she was taken from the facilty by family members in the 1940s only to be returned there by her husband Commodore. I am trying to confirm that.

Comment: Another question, [Finding medical records for Richmond State Hospital patient?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/13030/5200) discusses the availability of records for this hospital.

Comment: Eastern Indiana Hospital for the Insane turned into Richmond State Hospital, which is still active, so I think this is actually a duplicate of that other question.